# Make the selector of a paper-slider not hollow at value 0?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

By default, polymer's paper-slider component makes its slider hollow and whited out when the slider's value is 0.

```
<paper-slider value="0"></paper-slider>
```

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-slider?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-slider

[image]

How do I disable that behavior? I want the selector to look the same regardless of the slider's value. I tried perusing the attribute values in paper-slider's documentation, but found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it seems like varying `--paper-slider-knob-start-color` does the trick.